# Неправильно вычисляю выражение

Tags: c++, математика

В общем в одном из алгоритмов потребовалось вычислять квадратный корень из суммы квадратов двух аргументов. Казалось бы, всё просто и я написал `std::sqrt(std::pow(x,2)+std::pow(y,2))`, но чуть позже оказалось что некоторые тесты не проходят из-за этого вычесления (протрейсил и в этой строке получаются странные значения). Насколько я понял проблема в том что `std::pow(x,2)` превышает максимальное значение для типа x. Но ведь у результата будут брать корень и он станет снова маленьким? Как быть чтобы работало? Может есть какой-то другой алгоритм для вычисления выражения этого?

Comment: Вы, наверное, что-то выдумываете. В этом выражении нет зависимости от диапазона значений типа `x`. Вы умудрились переполнить плавающий тип? `double`? Или вы все таки привели ненастоящий код?

Comment: @AnT да у меня тип double, не знаю, ошибка точно в этой строке т.к. неправильные ответы получаются

Comment: Приведите пример неправильных результатов.

Comment: @break Что значит "неправильные"?

Comment: @AnT на калькуляторе по другому получается )) но уже дали ответ который работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте [`hypot`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/hypot) - она работает медленнее, но зато лишена описываемого вами недостатка.

И - ну уж хотя бы для возведения в квадрат я бы не стал пользоваться функцией `pow`... Неужели `x*x` длиннее `std::pow(x,2)`, если уж даже не рассматривать все остальные недостатки...

Comment: тесты проходит, спасибо!